# Double exclamation in fish shell

Tags: fish

In zsh, I can execute them.

```
$ sleep 1
$ echo !$ # !$ equals 1
$ echo !! # !! equals sleep 1
```

But I can't execute them in fish shell. 
Could tell me why and where the zsh documentation is?

Comment: Fish doesn't support !! !$ etc. Have a look at the answers here: http://superuser.com/q/719531/228642

Answer (score 6):

This is [history expansion](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#History-Expansion), which has a lot more to it then those simple examples.

Fish supports none of it (and probably never will). The usual workaround is to use keybindings. By default, alt-up and alt-down should go through the history token-wise, so you can press alt-up once to get what is effectively `!$`.

If you wish to prepend something to a command from history, recall that command, go to the beginning (e.g. with ctrl-a) and insert what you want.

Other possibilities are functions to bind e.g. `!!` to something to insert the previous command or to make a command called `!!`.

This is still discussed in [fish issue #288](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/288), though concensus seems to be against adding history expansion.

Comment: I will check them.